# Python: wild card pattern matching with memoization

Tags: python, python-2.x, regex, memoization

Here is my take on wild card pattern matching with memoization.

I would appreciate comments on clarity of the code, as well as suggested ways to improve readability and maintainability (for bigger projects).

Also, comments on how to change the algorithm to a better one (do it bottom to top instead for example) will also be very welcome.

Last thing I'm looking for are more test cases that will lead to greater code coverage, especially of the edge cases/boundary conditions. **Thanks**

*The commented sections are for collecting and printing out information that I used while debugging. The code is correct and those sections are no longer needed.*

---

```
class wild_card_pattern_matching:
    def __init__(self, p, s):
        self.m = [[None for _ in range(len(p) + 1)] for _ in range(len(s) + 1)]
        self.p = p
        self.s = s
        self.c = 0

    def match(self):
        def f(p,s,p_idx,s_idx):
            self.c += 1

            # end condition 1
            if p_idx == s_idx == 0:
                self.m[s_idx][p_idx] = True

            # end condition 2
            elif s_idx == 0:
                self.m[s_idx][p_idx] = f(p,s,p_idx-1,s_idx) and p[p_idx-1] == '*'

            # memo table init
            elif p_idx == 0:
                self.m[s_idx][p_idx] = False

            # use memo if possible
            elif self.m[s_idx][p_idx] != None:
                return self.m[s_idx][p_idx]

            # choose between ignoring * and "accepting" it
            elif p[p_idx-1] == '*': 
                self.m[s_idx][p_idx] = f(p,s,p_idx-1,s_idx) or f(p,s,p_idx,s_idx-1)

            # matching characters
            elif p[p_idx-1] == '?' or p[p_idx-1] == s[s_idx-1]: 
                self.m[s_idx][p_idx] = f(p,s,p_idx-1,s_idx-1)

            # pattern != string
            else: 
                self.m[s_idx][p_idx] = False

            return self.m[s_idx][p_idx]

        f(self.p,self.s,len(self.p), len(self.s))

        return self.m[-1][-1]

obj_ls = [wild_card_pattern_matching('*', '')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('*', 'a')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('*', 'b')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('a*', 'ab')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('*b', 'a')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('a*a', 'aba')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('*?*?', 'aa')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('c*d?*', 'cda')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('?*?*?*', 'xx0')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('a', 'a')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('', 'a')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('******a*a', 'a')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('******a*a', 'aa')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('******?*a', 'a')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('******a*a**', 'a')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('******a*a*', 'ababaab')]
obj_ls += [wild_card_pattern_matching('******a*a*', 'ababaa')]

print '         string         pattern    result    counter'
print '='*55
for w in obj_ls:
    print '%15s%15s%10r%10d' % (w.s,w.p,w.match(),w.c)
#    for l in w.m:
#        print l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at styling and naming guide, namely; [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Class names should be `CamelCase`d and method/attributes should be `snake_case`. Your variables are named like `s`, `p`, `c` etc. which does not make it clear at first glance what they represent, nor is there [a docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) available for reference.

---

That aside, running your code gives me:

```
         string         pattern    result    counter
=======================================================
                             *      True         2
              a              *      True         4
              b              *      True         4
             ab             a*      True         5
              a             *b     False         1
            aba            a*a      True         6
             aa           *?*?      True         5
            cda          c*d?*      True         6
            xx0         ?*?*?*      True         7
              a              a      True         2
              a                    False         1
              a      ******a*a     False        10
             aa      ******a*a      True        10
              a      ******?*a     False        10
              a    ******a*a**     False        35
        ababaab     ******a*a*      True        21
         ababaa     ******a*a*      True        19
```

where I noticed that your counter reached \$35\$ for the pattern `******a*a**`. In this case (and a few more similar cases), you can simply return `False` if your patter, after removing all `*` characters is still longer than the given string. Because then your string would never be able to cover the pattern.

As right now, you only have `*` and `?` characters; for **any length of characters** and **exactly one character**, the above method reduces your recursion by a lot in several given cases:

```
def match(self):
    if len(self.s) < len(self.p.replace('*', '')):
        return False
```

and the result:

```
         string         pattern    result    counter
=======================================================
  [=======================SAME======================]
              a                    False         1
              a      ******a*a     False         0
             aa      ******a*a      True        10
              a      ******?*a     False         0
              a    ******a*a**     False         0
        ababaab     ******a*a*      True        21
         ababaa     ******a*a*      True        19
```

The above snippet can also be placed inside your recursive `f` call. I still have to figure out under which section will it make more sense, but basically for any certain match fixed from pattern onto your string, if the remaining pattern satisfies the above length restriction, you can simply skip the rest of iterations.

---

For tests, make use of the python's [own `unittest` module](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/unittest) to create mocks. Have a set containing patterns and strings, and iteratively run the assertions on expected values.